# Map TAB key to switch splitted windows in vim

Tags: vim

How can I map the TAB key to switch among splitted windows in vim? I want to be able to type tab and switch among the windows, without having to press the leader key before pressing tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:nnoremap` or `:nmap` like discussed on this [vim.fandom page](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)).

```
:nnoremap <TAB> <C-W><C-W>
```